# Favicons with WP in a specific folder in 2023

Tags: favicon

I wanted to know the best implantation of favicon in wordpress.

My wordpress (updated) is running on a specific folder.
I used https://www.favicon-generator.org/ to start.

1. Should I still use all formats, or with the time it's not any more necessary to use them ?
   (57x57, 60x60, 72x72, 76x76, 114x114, 120x120, 144x144, 152x152, 180x180, 192x192, 32x32, 96x96, 16x16)
2. Should I copy the favicons at the root of www on my server (ovh) or at the root of the specified folder ?
3. Do we still need to put favicons files at the root or can I can use :

```
<link rel="icon" ...
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" ...
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" ...
```

4. I read somewhere that if I put files at the root, I don't need to specify them on `<link ...` meta tag

Thank for your reply and take care.

Nicolas.

Comment: This seems like it's a **favicon** question rather than a **WordPress** question. You might have better luck getting answers at [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I will (in 40 mn :)) , but in fact there's a question about WP within.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the official documentation? https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/create-a-favicon/#wordpress-version-4-3-or-later

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress in 2023, you can place your favicons in a specific folder by uploading them to the root directory of your theme or by using a custom folder within your theme directory. Then, you can reference the favicon in your theme's header.php file using the appropriate HTML code.